# Postgres pg_upgrade 13.2 to 14, returns out of shared memory. - Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)

Tags: postgresql, memory, amazon-linux, pg-upgrade

When attempting to upgrade a Postgres 13.2 database to 14, I receive the error "out of shared memory" when running the upgrade.

I have adjusted
`max_locks_per_transaction` to different and really high values,  and `max_connections` and other memory settings.  I have checked many configuration settings but have not found a reason why it cannot do the pg_dump/pg_upgrade with those settings.

OS is

```
Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo). ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
```

The error is as follows

```
command: "/usr/pgsql-14/bin/pg_dump" --host /usr/pgsql-14/bin --port 50432 --username postgres --schema-only --quote-all-identifiers --binary-upgrade --format=custom  --file="pg_upgrade_dump_18458.custom" 'dbname=aprivatedb' >> "pg_upgrade_dump_18458.log" 2>&1
pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  out of shared memory
HINT:  You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.
pg_dump: error: query was: LOCK TABLE "privatedata"."private_activities" IN ACCESS SHARE mode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you make these changes? Based on the error messages, it is the 13 cluster, not the 14 cluster, that needs `max_locks_per_transaction` raised.

pg_dump is run against the old cluster (using the new binary), not the new one.

Comment: This was exactly the issue.  Thank you !  The client updated the prior 13 conf file and the upgrade ran with no problem.  ( they had commented out max_locks_per_transaction and max_connections=100 )